# access http request parameters in grails gsp

Tags: http, grails, request

I am developing a web app in grails,in which on clicking of a link in email user redirected to my web page of grails.
My requirement is to access http request parameters that i have passed in link in email on my gsp page.

Ex:-
I have passed link `http://example.com/testpage?a=something&b=12345` and when user clicks on this link he redirect to `http://example.com/testpage` and then i can get values of parameters from request.
Like `a=something` and `b=12345`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the URL:

http://example.com/testpage?a=something&b=12345

put this in your GSP

```
<body>
<p>Say ${params.a}</p>
<p>count to 5, please: ${params.b}</p>
</body>
```

and you'll see this on your page:

Say something

count to 5, please: 12345

Answer (score 5):

In every Grails controller you have a params object. So you have to provide a valid URL which redirects the user to one of your controllers and starts one of your actions ie

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/myController/confirm?a=funnyParamA&b=funnyParamB

class MyController {
  def confirm = {
       def a = params.a
       def b = params.b

       ...

  }
}
```

Comment: sir i think you are not get my question i want to access params in gsp page not in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Basically while creating this clickable url `http://example.com/testpage`, you should create it something like,

```
http://example.com/testpage?a=${params.a}&b=${params.b}
```